# retornar responsive desde un método fetch

Tags: javascript

tengo una gran problemática. estoy tratando de retornar el responsive mediante Fetch, pero lo único que obtengo es como valor undefined.

agradecería si alguien me pudiera orientar y explicarme en que estoy fallando.
saludos.

les dejo el código que estoy realizando.

--Lo que estoy haciendo aquí es una clase llamada loadFetch. dentro de su estructura tengo declarado un constructor donde le paso su respectiva URL y la data si es necesario.

luego creo dos funciones. una esta realizando una llamada al controlador sin enviarle datos, y la otra le envía los datos correspondientes.

```js
class LoadFetch {
    constructor(Url, Data){
        this.url = Url;
        this.data = Data;
    }

    async FetchNotData() {
        await fetch(this.url, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
            return json;
        });
            
    }
    FetchWhitData() {
        fetch(this.url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).
            then(responsive =>  responsive);
    }
}
```

--Luego llamo la clase creada de la siguiente manera

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.getElementById('AddDesp').addEventListener('click', () => {
        
       const Datos = new loadFetch('../controlador/accion',null);
       
       const resultado = Datos.FetchNotData();
       
       console.log(resultado);//aqui obtengo por consola un undefined

        $('#modal-Add-Desp').modal('show');
    });
});
```

lo que trato de hacer con resultado es obtener el responsive y poder llenar los componentes que necesito.

espero puedan ayudarme.

saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dejo como evidencia la respuesta.
El problema ocurría debido a que cuando hacia click en el botón que ejecutaba la función fetchNotData. Esta se quedaba esperando resolver la promesa y como el evento click se desencadenaba inmediatamente, la función ya mencionada retornada nada, osea undefined

la solucion fue retornar una nueva promesa y en el evento click asignarle la propiedad asycn ademas de agregar la palabra await para esperar que la promesa se resolviera y retornara la data correspondiente.

Saludos cordiales.

```js
class LoadFetch {
    constructor(Url, Data){
        this.url = Url;
        this.data = Data;
    }

    FetchNotData() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            return resolve(
                fetch(this.url, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
                    return json;
                })
            );
        });
    }

    FetchWhitData() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            return resolve(
                fetch(this.url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(this.data),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(res => res.json()).then(responsive => {
                        return responsive;
                })
            );
        });
    }
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.getElementById('AddDesp').addEventListener('click', async ()  => {
        const Fetch = new LoadFetch('../WIPS/Cargar_Datos_Despacho_Sucursal', null);
        const resultado =  await Fetch.FetchNotData();

        console.log(resultado);

        const selectGrua = new LoadSelect('GRUA');
        const selectPartida = new LoadSelect('DESDE');
        const selectDestino = new LoadSelect('HACIA');
        const selectOrdenes = new LoadSelect('COD_ORDEN');
        selectGrua.createFileDefect(0, 'Seleccione una grua');
        selectPartida.createFileDefect(0, 'Seleccione un punto de partida');
        selectDestino.createFileDefect(0, 'Seleccione un punto de partida');
        selectOrdenes.createFileDefect(0, 'Seleccione un punto de partida');

        for (var i = 0; i < resultado[0].length; i++) {
            const Texto = `Patente: ${resultado[0][i].PATENTE} / Capacidad: ${resultado[0][i].CAPACIDAD}`;
            selectGrua.createSelect(resultado[0][i].ID_GRUA, Texto);
        }

        selectPartida.createSelect(resultado[2].COD_TIPO_UBICACION, resultado[2].TALLER);

        $('#modal-Add-Desp').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solo cambiale el nombre

Amigo esta mal el nombre de la clase

```
const Datos = new loadFetch('../controlador/accion',null);
```

es LoadFetch

```
const Datos = new LoadFetch('../controlador/accion',null);
```

Comment: fue un problema de redacción mio, en si no era el nombre el problema.

Comment: dejare como evidencia la solucion

Comment: La solucion  cual es?

Comment: ya publique las respuesta amigo, trate de explicarla lo mejor posible